# Python can't run absolute script?

Tags: python, windows

I encountered such a weird situation:

```
naivechou@naivechou/~>python test.py
test
naivechou@naivechou/~>pwd
/home/naivechou
naivechou@naivechou/~>python /home/naivechou/test.py
C:\toolchain\python\python.exe: can't open file '/home/naivechou/test.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

My working directory is `/home/naivechou/`, `test.py` is in there.
If I run `test.py` with absolute path, I'll get an error message of `No such file or directory`.But everything will be fine if I enter that directory and then run it. What's wrong with python?

Comment: I assume you're using Windows, but you are saying your working directory is `/home/naivechou/`. Will you please give more information?

Comment: I don't believe Windows uses forward-slashes as directory separators on the command line.  Try `python \home\naivechou\test.py` and see what happens.

Comment: @JohnGordon This is a wart of `cmd.exe`. Windows (the kernel, the API) perfectly understands forward slashes.

Comment: Oh, I miss something.
I use cygwin.

Comment: does tab completion work in cygwin? If so, you could try using it to validate the path.

Comment: @phd, the kernel sees forward slash as just another name character. The only path separator in the kernel is backslash. The user-mode Windows API uses runtime library functions in ntdll.dll to translate DOS paths to NT object-manager paths that use an [`OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff557749) record, which also generalizes the working directory concept to a `RootDirectory` handle. If you open `C:/Temp/test.txt`, the system actually opens `\??\C:\Temp\test.txt`. How `\??\C:` gets resolved to something like `\Device\HarddiskVolume2` is complicated in itself.

Comment: @phd, also, if the OP weren't using Cygwin, FYI this would still have nothing to do with CMD. Windows Python has no problem with forward slashes in a script path, since it uses WinAPI functions that handle this. CMD has nothing do with parsing the command line for child processes. They get a command-line string and do all of their own parsing.

Answer (score 0):

Try moving into the folder where the python script is located and do a "ls" command there in Linux. if windows then do 'dir'. if you see the required file there then execute the following command

```
C:\location_where_the_script_is> python yourfile.py
```

Comment: He's already doing this.  It's literally the first command in his example.

Comment: He is moving into the folder, but not checking whether the file is present in the folder or not

Comment: True.  But he doesn't get a "file not found" error from Python, so it has to be there.

Comment: I had said that above, and test it actually.
When I was located on the path of script, I can run it without any error.
My question is, when I run the script with absolute path form, it will result to error.

Comment: @KalyanReddy:
The script exists indeed. Only difference is how I run it.
If I run the script with absolute path, it will fail.
If I enter the path of script then run it, it runs well without error.

Answer (score 0):

For commands entered on the command line, Windows doesn't recognize forward-slashes as directory separators.

Your second example is looking *in the current directory* for the literal filename `/home/naivechou/test.py`, and of course such a filename does not exist.

Use backslashes instead, as is the Windows way:

`python \home\naivechou\test.py`

Comment: Windows python.exe has no problem with using forward slash in a script path. CMD has nothing to do with parsing that. It's a problem to assume the working drive is the same volume that has `/home` on it. Windows doesn't have a single root. However, it turns out the OP is using Cygwin, so that's not an issue -- directly. The problem is that the OP is running Windows Python (i.e. `C:\toolchain\python\python.exe`) and passing it a Unix path as if it were Cygwin `python`.